# Quotient group $G = \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G = \mathbb Q /\mathbb Z$, where $\mathbb Q$ = group of rational numbers with addition and $\mathbb Z$ = group of integers with addition. Since $\mathbb Q$ is abelian, the subgroup $\mathbb Z$ is normal, hence $G$ is a factor group. Now my doubt is 
1) Is $G$ cyclic?

2) If $G$ is not Cyclic, then whether it has cyclic subgroup? and if it has what are the orders of cyclic subgroups of $G$?

Please share your answers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ G $ is not cyclic. Hint: let $ g $ be a generator, then some power of $ g $ must be $\mathbb{Z}$ and its powers are periodic, meaning the cyclic subgroup it generates is finite.

G has cyclic subgroups of arbitrary (finite) cardinality: pick $ g= 1/n + \mathbb{Z} $.

Answer (score 2):

$G$ can't be cyclic, since the existence of a single generator $\alpha$ of $G$ would imply that there are only finitely many rational numbers. (Can you see why?) As for cyclic subgroups, consider what happens to $\frac{1}{n}$ when you keep adding it to itself, for each $n \ge 1$.

Answer (score 2):

To add to what others said, note that $S^1 = \mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ is the circle group; that is, the set of complex numbers of length (or modulus) 1, with the operation of complex number multiplication. Note that $|wz| = |w| |z|$ so the unit circle is indeed closed under multiplication.

Any element of $S^1$ can be written as $e^{\alpha2\pi i}$ where $\alpha \in [0,1)$.

$\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ is the subset of $S^1$ consisting of those elements for which $\alpha$ is rational. You can see that each element of $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ generates a cyclic subgroup, but no single element generates all of $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$.